# Player Name Not Showing On Sign Bukkit

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am quite new to bukkit but I do not understand why this happens. The player name does not show on a sign using bukkit. It worked before but I do not know what I did that stopped it from working. I am using spigot 1.9. The player name is displayed using 'Bukkit.broadcastMessage()' however.

Here is a part of my code:

```
if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("sign") && sender instanceof Player){

    Player player = (Player) sender;
    Location location = player.getLocation();
    World someWorld = Bukkit.getServer().getWorld("world");

    double playerx = location.getX();
    double playery = location.getY();
    double playerz = location.getZ();

    int px = (int)playerx;
    int py = (int)playery;
    int pz = (int)playerz;

    Location nLoc = new Location(someWorld, px+1, py+1, pz);

    Location sLoc = new Location(someWorld, px+1, py+1, pz-1);


    Block block = someWorld.getBlockAt(nLoc);
    block.setType(Material.WOOD);

    Block block1 = someWorld.getBlockAt(sLoc);
    block1.setType(Material.WALL_SIGN);
    Sign sign = (Sign) block1.getState();
    sign.setLine(0, "Hello "+player.getName());
    sign.setLine(1, "Welcome To My");
    sign.setLine(2, "Server!");


    Bukkit.broadcastMessage("Name: "+player.getName());
    sign.update(true);
```

Comment: I tested your code and everything worked, including the name being written on the first line of the sign. Are you sure the plugin you are testing is using this exact code? Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: No, I am getting no errors. It's probably a bug on my spigot build then. I will try updating and will tell you if it fixed the problem or not.